# Upgrade Magento CE v1.4.1.0 to 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, upgrade

hey guys i need to upgrade Magento CE v1.4.1.0 to 1.7.0.2 I need a proper way to do it pls do help

I am new to it so a step by step guide will be great

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say but probably a good idea to mention: before any upgrade you need to make sure that you have **full backup of the files & DB**. I also strongly recommend using a **staging environment** for testing the upgrade process.

Assuming proper code techniques were applied to your Magento store, upgrading Magento's code and DB is relatively easy. The tricky part is when you have a lot of third party extensions and a custom theme. In some cases, the extensions and the theme files are tied into a specific version of Magento so once your core files upgrade some portions or features will break as a result. Hence, in general you will need to upgrade three main areas: Core, Theme, and Extensions. These are the steps that you will need to follow:

### Core Upgrade

1. Backup! Backup! Backup!
2. Work on staging environment
3. Make a list of all the third party extensions
4. Disable all third party extensions (set 'false' in all xml files)
5. Make a list of all the local modifications (all files under /app/code/local/*)
6. Update all core files (Download and unzip files from the latest stable version to your webroot)
7. Clear cache, logout and log back in to Admin area
8. If no errors occurred, proceed to *Theme Upgrade*
9. If errors occurred you need to look for local file modifications (/app/code/local/*) that break the new version of DB or files. These modifications need to be corrected or removed.

### Theme Upgrade

1. Between 1.4 and 1.7 there were a lot of changes, even if the admin area upgraded properly it is likely some things will be broken on the theme level. Two way to address this: *A.* Get a new 1.7 compatible theme or *B.* Upgrade the current theme.
2. To install new theme files, simply unpack new theme files and configure the store to use this new theme.
3. To upgrade existing theme, compare file by file and layout by layout. Find all the files under /app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/* and compare them with their counterparts which can be found at /app/design/frontend/base/default/*. **Make sure to copy version modifications but leave theme related differences**.
4. With each file you need to test the frontend or the relevant section of the site.

### Third Party Extensions Upgrade

1. You will need to first check and get the latest version of each third party extension.
2. One by one enable each extension and check that everything works properly.
3. If one extension breaks, either fix it or get a different extension with same features. This way you isolate any potential issues from third party extension that will break the upgrade process.
4. If you are getting rid of a third party extension, make sure to delete all of its files including xml, frontend, skin, and any JS files if exist.
5. If an extension had its own data and it got lost in the upgrade process, you can retrieve the data from the DB backup. Notice that well written extensions will upgrade properly if you follow these steps.
6. Repeat the above steps for all extensions. Don't forget to test for the features the extensions add to Magento and make sure you also run general testing to the frontend and backend of your shopping cart.
7. Some extensions will need to be reinstalled via the connect manager or even manually.

As you go through the above process, I recommend to log all the actions that you took to get the Magento to upgrade properly. Some extensions or theme files will have certain exceptions that will need to be repeated on the live website. That will give you a blue print of Upgrading your live Magento site.

Comment: thanks Ron for your reply but I upgraded before u post this message. What I did took a fresh magento and kept the old database after configure the database with magento I kept the old theme and design in it and its working fine. I have gone thought the site and its working fine. Is there any thing I need to check since there are lot of changes between 1.4.1.0 to 1.7.0.2 as mentioned by you.

Comment: There were several architectural and data structure changes between 1.4 and 1.5 AND between 1.6 and 1.7. If you used a fresh copy of Magento, you should be fine, this is the easiest way to upgrade safely - however you loose all of your custom features and design. In order to be 100% sure that the upgrade went well, I would recommend that you run the [DB Repair Tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool) which will check that your DB is not corrupted in any way.